# Injecting JS in UIWebview's didStartLoad methoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cordova

Facing a strange issue on injecting javascript in my **UIWebView**. I was able to inject the JS strings in 
**UIWebView** **webViewDidStartLoad** method for the first time.When **location.reload()** is triggered again from the HTML page the JS are not loaded again from **UIWebView** **webViewDidStartLoad** method.

Once the **UIWebView** is loaded i can inject it from **webViewDidFinishLoad** but my concern why it works for the first time not on next reload.

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

    NSString *cordovaScript = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cordova" ofType:@"js"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:cordovaScript];

    // Loading Plugin.js file
    NSString *childWindowScript = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Plugin" ofType:@"js"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:childWindowScript];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I made a small delay in loading the JS, If **webViewDidStartLoad**  is called for the second time.